# How get survival function estimates from Aalen's additive regression?

Tags: r, self-study, survival

The Aalen model assumes that the cumulative hazard H(t) for a subject can be expressed as a(t) + X B(t), where a(t) is a time-dependent intercept term, X is the vector of covariates for the subject (possibly time-dependent), and B(t) is a time-dependent matrix of coefficients.

My intuition was that coefficient plots from `plot.aareg` produce cumulative hazards for each explanatory variable and intercept (or time-dependent baseline hazard). But should the cumulative hazard function be non-decreasing?

Anyhow, is there any way to get the survival function from this model?

[image: Intercept coef]

```
library(survival)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
lfit <- aareg(Surv(time, status) ~ sex , data=lung,
              nmin=1)
plot(lfit)
tibble(t=lfit$times, coef=lfit$coefficient[,'Intercept']) %>%
  group_by(t) %>%
  summarise(baseline_coef_t=sum(coef)) %>%
  mutate(baseline_cumhaz=cumsum(baseline_coef_t),
         baseline_survival=exp(-baseline_cumhaz))
```

[image: survival and hazards]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991) (Second Edition) devote Chapter 10 to additive models. Practical Notes to Section 10.2 discuss this matter.

> 3. The estimates of the baseline hazard rate are not constrained to be nonnegative by this least-squares estimation procedure...

Similarly, with respect to cumulative hazards and associated survival curves either via Nelson-Aalen (your estimate) or product-limit approaches, they warn:

> 6. ... Some care is needed in interpreting either estimate because $\hat H(t | Z)$ [estimated cumulative hazard] need not be monotone over the time interval.

What you found is thus to be expected. You might consider using the `slope` values returned for the model as linear approximations to the cumulative hazard. From the manual page for `summary.aareg()`:

> The slope is based on a weighted linear regression to the cumulative coefficient plot, and may be a useful measure of the overall size of the effect... (Of course the plots [of coefficients over time] are often highly non-linear, so it is only a rough substitute).

You might consider flexible fits of the cumulative hazards that enforce monotonicity. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/197509/28500) has some suggestions. You probably need to weight the individual estimates over time similarly to how the `slope` values are estimated by `summary.aareg()`.

My sense, as a non-expert in additive models, is that they are best used for evaluating associations of predictors with outcome in a highly flexible way, rather than for modeling survival functions.